# How to set 1440×900 screen resolution?

Tags: graphics, resolution, asus

I have an ASUS wide screen on a dual boot machine. In Windows screen resolution is 1440×900, but in Ubuntu the only settings available are 1424×768 or less. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: What's your graphics?

Comment: Also, post output of `xrandr` command.

Comment: @ZDroid correct, but I would suggest to have a search on AU for xrandr. This must have been asked before :-) edit: examples from the 'related' section: http://askubuntu.com/questions/98852/screen-resolution-not-right-on-a-new-install?rq=1

Comment: LOL... I already posted answer :D

Comment: Here are some help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/716574/screen-resolution-1440x900-not-listed https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1824207 http://askubuntu.com/questions/138408/how-to-add-display-resolution-fo-an-lcd-in-ubuntu-12-04-xrandr-problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screen resolution 1440x900 not listed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/716574/screen-resolution-1440x900-not-listed)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System settings > Displays**. You can change resolution in that. Something like this...

[image: Displays]

If System Settings doesn't do work, open Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T). Run `xrandr`. Find what device has 1424×768 resolution (I call it *name* in command down). After that...
`xrandr --output name --mode 1440x900`

Maybe problem with your graphics driver.

For AMD → http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx
For Nvidia → http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html

After installing this drivers reboot you machine.

`sudo reboot`

Comment: How is that an answer? First, `mode 1440x900` is obviously not available, and second, why is the OP supposed to go to AMD and Nvidia websites? It's Ubuntu after all.

Comment: I think same... and has same problem with monitor. When I go to terminal and type `mode RESxRES` all works. You can try with FLOSS graphics, but that isn't better that property :(

Comment: The point (still) is you don't need to go the their websites. Proprietary graphics card drivers, if available, can and should be installed from the official repositories or, at best, a PPA.

Answer (score -1):

try these options:

1. Xrandr, xrandr is a command line tool for doing all kinds of settings for monitors, you may be able to force that setting and have it save the profile and have it auto load when logging into your system. read more about xrandr here. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr

option 2: if that doesn't work I would say you might have to face messing with xorg, and that's where things get messy, if that is the case you will want to read here, and then look at the wiki for resolutions etc https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg

NOTE: please check your software update settings and see if any of the other drivers for your gfx card may work better to give you that option you need.

I hope the first one works for you, I have been fixing issues that way for 6 years.

best of luck- Larry